Map colours not showing correctly, all SpatRaster values converted to 1 when using crop and mask
I am following this tutorial to create a 3d land cover map and this is the complete code:
library(terra)
library(giscoR)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)
library(elevatr)
library(png)
library(rayshader)
library(magick)

# 2. COUNTRY BORDERS ----

country_sf <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(
  country = "BA",
  resolution = "1"
)

plot(sf::st_geometry(country_sf))

png("bih-borders.png")
plot(sf::st_geometry(country_sf))
dev.off()

# 3. DOWNLOAD ESRI LAND COVER TILES ----

urls <- c(
  "https://lulctimeseries.blob.core.windows.net/lulctimeseriesv003/lc2022/33T_20220101-20230101.tif",
  "https://lulctimeseries.blob.core.windows.net/lulctimeseriesv003/lc2022/34T_20220101-20230101.tif"
)

for(url in urls){
  download.file(
    url = url,
    destfile = basename(url),
    mode = "wb"
  )
}

# 4. LOAD TILES ----

raster_files <- list.files(
  path = getwd(),
  pattern = "20230101.tif$",
  full.names = T
)

crs <- "EPSG:4326"

for(raster in raster_files){
  rasters <- terra::rast(raster)
  
  country <- country_sf |>
    sf::st_transform(
      crs = terra::crs(
        rasters
      )
    )
  
  land_cover <- terra::crop(
    rasters,
    terra::vect(
      country
    ),
    snap = "in",
    mask = T
  ) |>
    terra::aggregate(
      fact = 5,
      fun = "modal"
    ) |>
    terra::project(crs)
  
  terra::writeRaster(
    land_cover,
    overwrite=TRUE,
    paste0(
      raster,
      "_bosnia",
      ".tif"
    )
  )
}

# 5. LOAD VIRTUAL LAYER ----

r_list <- list.files(
  path = getwd(),
  pattern = "_bosnia",
  full.names = T
)

land_cover_vrt <- terra::vrt(
  r_list,
  "bosnia_land_cover_vrt.vrt",
  overwrite = T
)

# 6. FETCH ORIGINAL COLOURS ----

ras <- terra::rast(
  raster_files[[1]]
)

raster_color_table <- do.call(
  data.frame,
  terra::coltab(ras)
)

head(raster_color_table)

hex_code <- ggtern::rgb2hex(
  r = raster_color_table[,2],
  g = raster_color_table[,3],
  b = raster_color_table[,4]
)

# 7. ASSIGN COLORS TO RASTER----

cols <- hex_code[c(2:3, 5:6, 8:12)]

from <- unique_vals
to <- t(col2rgb(cols))
land_cover_vrt <- na.omit(land_cover_vrt)

land_cover_bosnia <- terra::subst(
  land_cover_vrt,
  from = from,
  to = to,
  names = cols
)

terra::plotRGB(land_cover_bosnia)

# 8. DIGITAL ELEVATION MODEL ----

elev <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(
  locations = country_sf,
  z = 9, clip = "locations"
)

crs_lambert <-
  "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_frfs"

land_cover_bosnia_resampled <- terra::resample(
  x = land_cover_bosnia,
  y = terra::rast(elev),
  method = "near"
) |>
  terra::project(crs_lambert)

terra::plotRGB(land_cover_bosnia_resampled)

img_file <- "land_cover_bosnia.png"

terra::writeRaster(
  land_cover_bosnia_resampled,
  img_file,
  overwrite = T,
  NAflag = 255
)

img <- png::readPNG(img_file)


# 9. RENDER SCENE ----


elev_lambert <- elev |>
  terra::rast() |>
  terra::project(crs_lambert)

elmat <- rayshader::raster_to_matrix(
  elev_lambert
)

h <- nrow(elev_lambert)
w <- ncol(elev_lambert)

elmat |>
  rayshader::height_shade(
    texture = colorRampPalette(
      cols[9]
    )(256)
  ) |>
  rayshader::add_overlay(
    img,
    alphalayer = 1
  ) |>
  rayshader::plot_3d(
    elmat,
    zscale = 12,
    solid = F,
    shadow = T,
    shadow_darkness = 1,
    background = "white",
    windowsize = c(
      w / 5, h / 5
    ),
    zoom = .5,
    phi = 85,
    theta = 0
  )

rayshader::render_camera(
  zoom = .58
)

# 10. RENDER OBJECT ----

u <- "https://dl.polyhaven.org/file/ph-assets/HDRIs/hdr/4k/air_museum_playground_4k.hdr"
hdri_file <- basename(u)

download.file(
  url = u,
  destfile = hdri_file,
  mode = "wb"
)

filename <- "3d_land_cover_bosnia-dark.png"

rayshader::render_highquality(
  filename = filename,
  preview = F,
  light = F,
  environment_light = hdri_file,
  intensity_env = 1,
  rotate_env = 90,
  interactive = F,
  parallel = T,
  width = w * 1.5,
  height = h * 1.5
)

# 11. PUT EVERYTHING TOGETHER ----

c(
  "#419bdf", "#397d49", "#7a87c6", 
  "#e49635", "#c4281b", "#a59b8f", 
  "#a8ebff", "#616161", "#e3e2c3"
)

legend_name <- "land_cover_legend.png"
png(legend_name)
par(family = "mono")

plot(
  NULL,
  xaxt = "n",
  yaxt = "n",
  bty = "n",
  ylab = "",
  xlab = "",
  xlim = 0:1,
  ylim = 0:1,
  xaxs = "i",
  yaxs = "i"
)
legend(
  "center",
  legend = c(
    "Water",
    "Trees",
    "Crops",
    "Built area",
    "Rangeland"
  ),
  pch = 15,
  cex = 2,
  pt.cex = 1,
  bty = "n",
  col = c(cols[c(1:2, 4:5, 9)]),
  fill = c(cols[c(1:2, 4:5, 9)]),
  border = "grey20"
)
dev.off()

# filename <- "land-cover-bih-3d-b.png"

lc_img <- magick::image_read(
  filename
)

my_legend <- magick::image_read(
  legend_name
)

my_legend_scaled <- magick::image_scale(
  magick::image_background(
    my_legend, "none"
  ), 2500
)

p <- magick::image_composite(
  magick::image_scale(
    lc_img, "x7000" 
  ),
  my_legend_scaled,
  gravity = "southwest",
  offset = "+100+0"
)

magick::image_write(
  p, "3d_bosnia_land_cover_final.png"
)

I am using MacOS, R version = 4.4.0, rayshader version = 0.35.7, terra version = 1.7-78.
This is my output:

However, this is what the output should be like:

I am using MacOS, R version = 4.4.0, rayshader version = 0.35.7, terra version = 1.7-78.

For some reason, the values in large SpatRaster files are all converted to 1 if you call mask inside crop(). The solution is to run mask() separately. I'm not sure whether this is caused by a hardware issue or not, but if you replace the for() loop in step 4 with:
for(raster in raster_files){
  
  rasters <- rast(raster)
  
  country <- country_sf |>
    st_transform(crs(rasters))
  
  land_cover <- crop(rasters, vect(country), snap = "in")
  
  land_cover <-  mask(land_cover, vect(country)) |>
    aggregate(fact = 5, fun = "modal") |>
    project(crs)
  
  writeRaster(land_cover,
              paste0(raster, "_bosnia", ".tif"),
              overwrite = TRUE)
  
}

then run the rest of the code, the output 3d_bosnia_land_cover_final.png file will show the correct colours.

Thank you so much that worked for me!! :)

This is probably related to this bug: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1473 It should be fixed in the dev version.
